Does every SES of injective bounded cochain complexes split?
Question: Does every short exact sequence of injective bounded cochain complexes, $0\rightarrow I^\bullet\rightarrow J^\bullet\rightarrow K^\bullet\rightarrow 0$, split?
I am interested in a discrete setting. Let $\Pi$ be a finite poset, and fix a field $k$. The objects I am interested in are equivalently:

a finitely dimensional $k$-representation of the poset $\Pi$,
a finitely dimensional sheaf on $\Pi$ with Alexandrov topology with $k$ coefficients,
a finitely dimensional module over the bound quiver algebra over $k$ corresponding to $\Pi$.

For any of those we can define injective objects, and bounded cochain complexes. An injective cochain complexes is a cochain complexes $I^{\bullet}$ such that each $I^{d}$ is injective.
Given a SES in the question, $0\rightarrow I^d \rightarrow J^d \rightarrow K^d \rightarrow 0$ splits for every $d$. But can this split be done consistently over all degrees so taht it is compatible with the cochain maps?

No, if that was true the category of finite dimensional representations of your poset would be semi simple. Notice that you can realize any sort exact sequence of representations as $H^0$ of a short exact sequence of such complexes.

Is it easy to construct / find an example of such SES that does not split?

Yes, it’s rather elementary. Think of 0 < 1.
